# \resizebox and pdftricks: Argument of \next has an extra }

Tags: graphics, pdftricks

I used `\resizebox` to resize my tabular environments. Since I have to get rid of postscript stuff in order to use `xelatex`, I am experimenting with `pdftricks`. But it seems to be impossible to use `\resizebox` outside of the `pdfdisplay` environment. Is there anything I can do about this?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdftricks}

\begin{psinputs}

\end{psinputs}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{pdfdisplay}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
xx & xx
\end{tabular}
\end{pdfdisplay}
}

\end{document}
```

Edit: OK, here is another problem: The code below works with the `book` class, but does not work with the `scrbook` class. I guess this is due to the textarea size set within `scrbook`. I could not figure out a way to do this properly (maybe by loading `typearea` in the include section), but hacked `pdftricks` instead to call the documentclass `scrbook`. This works but ....

```
\documentclass{book}
%\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pdftricks}

\begin{psinputs}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{tree-dvips}
\end{psinputs}


\begin{document}

This is some text and the figure should be the size of the text not larger and not smaller.
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{pdfdisplay}
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
      \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
        \multicolumn{5}{c}{\node{sign}{sign}}\\[5ex]
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\node{root}{root}} &        & \node{word}{word}       & \node{phrase}{phrase}\\[3ex]
        \node{noun}{noun-root} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\node{verb}{verb-root}}  &  & \node{hp}{headed-phrase} \\[3ex]
        & \node{iv}{intransitive-verb} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\node{tv}{transitive-verb}}            & \node{hap}{head-complement-phrase}\\[3ex]
        & \node{siv}{strict-intr-verb}                 & \node{stv}{strict-transitive-verb} & \node{dv}{ditransitive-verb} \\[3ex]
        & \node{schlaf}{schlaf-}           & \node{lieb}{lieb-}                  & \node{geb}{geb-}\\
        & (`to sleep') & (`to love') & (`to give')\\
      \end{tabular}
      \nodeconnect{sign}{root}\nodeconnect{sign}{word}\nodeconnect{sign}{phrase}%
      \nodeconnect{root}{noun}\nodeconnect{root}{verb}\nodeconnect{phrase}{hp}%
      \nodeconnect{hp}{hap}%
      \nodeconnect{verb}{iv}\nodeconnect{verb}{tv}\nodeconnect{tv}{stv}\nodeconnect{tv}{dv}%
      \nodeconnect{iv}{siv}%
                  {\makedash{4pt}%
                    \nodeconnect{siv}{schlaf}\nodeconnect{stv}{lieb}\nodeconnect{dv}{geb}%
                  }%
    }
  \end{pdfdisplay}
\end{figure}

This is some text and the figure should be the size of the text not larger and not smaller.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

use it this way:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pdftricks}
\begin{psinputs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\end{psinputs}

\begin{document}

\begin{pdfdisplay}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lll}
xx & xx
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{pdfdisplay}

\end{document}
```

However, using package `auto-pst-pdf` or `xelatex` is much more easier.

Comment: OK. Thanks! I tried this, but forgot to include graphicx in the psinputs. I am trying to get rid of postscript because I want to use xelatex for type setting Persian, but this is not that easy. A lot of linguists use tree-dvips, which connects things labeled as nodes \node{x}{Text}. This can be done in the middle of the text. I do not know how to replace this.

Comment: With `xelatex` you can use PostScript without any restriction.

Comment: OK. Then I will ask in a separate question how to do this with tree-dvips. I tried, but could not get it to work.